# Nested class in Class-validator

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I have following struture

DetailDTO
Id
OrderInfo: OrderInfoDTO
type : String

OrderInfoDTO
Name : String
Address : String

If I want use class validator to validate Name under orderInfoDTO using a attribute from parent 'type' using custom validator, what is the best way to pass the parent class attribute to validate method under custom validator.